# Hugging face tokenizer cannot load files properly

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to train a translation model from sratch using HuggingFace's BartModel architecture. I am using a ByteLevelBPETokenizer to tokenize things.

The issue that I am facing is that when I save the tokenizer after training it is not loaded properly even though it apparently creates the correct vocab.json and merges.txt file.

```
from tokenizers import ByteLevelBPETokenizer

# Initialize a tokenizer
tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer()

# Customize training
tokenizer.train(files=['/work/vaibhav/iwslt14/de-en/train.en', '/work/vaibhav/iwslt14/de-en/train.de'], vocab_size=8000, min_frequency=2, special_tokens=[
    "<s>",
    "<pad>",
    "</s>",
    "<unk>",
    "<mask>",
])

# Save files to disk
print(tokenizer)
tokenizer.save_model("tokens")
```

This is how I am training and saving my tokenizer. The print statement prints this:

```
Tokenizer(vocabulary_size=8000, model=ByteLevelBPE, add_prefix_space=False, lowercase=False, dropout=None, unicode_normalizer=None, continuing_subword_prefix=None, end_of_word_suffix=None, trim_offsets=False)
```

However when I try to load the tokenizer while training my model by the following lines of code:

```
#get the tokenizer
tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer()
tokenizer.from_file('tokens/vocab.json', 'tokens/merges.txt')
print(tokenizer)
return tokenizer
```

Then the print statement prints the following:

```
Tokenizer(vocabulary_size=0, model=ByteLevelBPE, add_prefix_space=False, lowercase=False, dropout=None, unicode_normalizer=None, continuing_subword_prefix=None, end_of_word_suffix=None, trim_offsets=False)
```

Now this is weird to me because the vocab_size is supposed to be 8000 not zero and because of this it stops working basically. If I retrain and use it directly without saving and loading then it works but that's not efficient.

This is a view into the vocab.json (truncated).

```
{"<s>":0,"<pad>":1,"</s>":2,"<unk>":3,"<mask>":4,"!":5,"\"":6,"#":7,"$":8,"%":9,"&":10,"'":11,"(":12,")":13,"*":14,"+":15,",":16,"-":17,".":18,"/":19,"0":20,"1":21,"2":22,"3":23,"4":24,"5":25,"6":26,"7":27,"8":28,"9":29,":":30,";":31,"<":32,"=":33,">":34,"?":35,"@":36,"A":37,"B":38,"C":39,"D":40,"E":41,"F":42,"G":43,"H":44,"I":45,"J":46,"K":47,"L":48,"M":49,"N":50,"O":51,"P":52,"Q":53,"R":54,"S":55,"T":56,"U":57,"V":58,"W":59,"X":60,"Y":61,"Z":62,"[":63,"\\":64,"]":65,"^":66,"_":67,"`":68,"a":69,"b":70,"c":71,"d":72,"e":73,"f":74,"g":75,"h":76,"i":77,"j":78,"k":79,"l":80,"m":81,"n":82,"o":83,"p":84,"q":85,"r":86,"s":87,"t":88,"u":89,"v":90,"w":91,"x":92,"y":93,"z":94,"{":95,"|":96,"}":97,"~":98,"¡":99,"¢":100,"£":101,"¤":102,"¥":103,"¦":104,"§":105,"¨":106,"©":107,"ª":108,"«":109,"¬":110,"®":111,"¯":112,"°":113,"±":114,"²":115,"³":116,"´":117,"µ":118,"¶":119,"·":120,"¸":121,"¹":122,"º":123,"»":124,"¼":125,"½":126,"¾":127,"¿":128,"À":129,"Á":130,"Â":131,"Ã":132,"Ä":133,"Å":134,"Æ":135,"Ç":136,"È":137,"É":138,"Ê":139,"Ë":140,"Ì":141,"Í":142,"Î":143,"Ï":144,"Ð":145,"Ñ":146,"Ò":147,"Ó":148,"Ô":149,"Õ":150,"Ö":151,"×":152,"Ø":153,"Ù":154,"Ú":155,"Û":156,"Ü":157,"Ý":158,"Þ":159,"ß":160,"à":161,"á":162,"â":163,"ã":164,"ä":165,"å":166,"æ":167,"ç":168,"è":169,"é":170,"ê":171,"ë":172,"ì":173,"í":174,"î":175,"ï":176,"ð":177,"ñ":178,"ò":179,"ó":180,"ô":181,"õ":182,"ö":183,"÷":184,"ø":185,"ù":186,"ú":187,"û":188,"ü":189,"ý":190,"þ":191,"ÿ":192,"Ā":193,"ā":194,"Ă":195,"ă":196,"Ą":197,"ą":198,"Ć":199,"ć":200,"Ĉ":201,"ĉ":202,"Ċ":203,"ċ":204,"Č":205,"č":206,"Ď":207,"ď":208,"Đ":209,"đ":210,"Ē":211,"ē":212,"Ĕ":213,"ĕ":214,"Ė":215,"ė":216,"Ę":217,"ę":218,"Ě":219,"ě":220,"Ĝ":221,"ĝ":222,"Ğ":223,"ğ":224,"Ġ":225,"ġ":226,"Ģ":227,"ģ":228,"Ĥ":229,"ĥ":230,"Ħ":231,"ħ":232,"Ĩ":233,"ĩ":234,"Ī":235,"ī":236,"Ĭ":237,"ĭ":238,"Į":239,"į":240,"İ":241,"ı":242,"Ĳ":243,"ĳ":244,"Ĵ":245,"ĵ":246,"Ķ":247,"ķ":248,"ĸ":249,"Ĺ":250,"
```

This is a view into the merges.txt (truncated).

```
#version: 0.2 - Trained by `huggingface/tokenizers`
e n
e r
i n
Ġ t
c h
Ġ a
Ġ d
Ġ w
Ġ s
Ġt h
n d
i e
e s
i s
a t
o n
i t
Ġ m
a s
a n
r e
Ġth e
Ġ h
```

As you can see the files are normal. Any help with this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured this out myself, finally! There is some error in huggingface code so i loaded the tokenizer like this and it worked.

```
tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer('tokens/vocab.json', 'tokens/merges.txt')
```